# Media Queries in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, media-queries

I was wondering how to write these values:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.3), (min-resolution: 124.8dpi), (max-device-width: 550px)
```

So that I can write an if clause like so except with the values from above:

```
if (window.screenWidth >=550 || window.screenWidth >=550 ) {
}
```

Comment: Isn't the whole point of a media query so that you can specify rules in CSS based on device parameters with out javascript?  FYI, if, using javascript, you want to make a CSS rule apply to a document, you can put the rule on a class and add the class to the body tag with javascript.

Comment: This may help http://flippinawesome.org/2014/03/24/using-media-queries-in-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe media queries like those are available as JS `window` properties, though there may be plugins out there that handle these queries.

One solution is to use the normal queries in CSS to style an arbitrary element a specific way that can simply be detected via javascript.

CSS:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.3), (min-resolution: 124.8dpi), (max-device-width: 550px) {
    head { font-family: 'someValue'; }
}
```

JS (w/ jQuery):

```
$(function() {
    var foo = $('head').css('fontFamily').split("\"").join("").split("'").join(""); // split/joins needed for cross-browser compatibility
    if(foo === 'someValue') {
        doStuff();
    } else if(foo === 'someOtherValue') {
        doOtherStuff();
    }
}
```

Kind of a hack, but it works. I use a variation of that code for responsive designs.